# TypeError: string indices must be integers - Python3

Tags: python, typeerror

**Problem**

So, my problem is that I'm getting a `TypeError: string indices must be integers`, on this line: `userCHR += str(user[i])`, but the code looks fine to me. Can someone help me?

**Python Code**

```
user = input("Please enter a string: ")
user = user.upper()

userCHR = ""

for i in user:
    userCHR += str(user[i])

print(userCHR)
```

Comment: Add `print(repr(i))` ... you'll see its a string, not an integer.

Comment: I can't figure out what you code is trying to do. What is the goal?

Comment: What do you think you're accomplishing with that loop? Please continue with whatever tutorial you're using.

Comment: You cannot iterate both by value (`for element in iterable`) and by index (`for i in range(iterable)`). Pick one and use it. But I recommend using the former as it would be consider more idomatic in Python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A for loop returns the character in the string, not the integer location, in Python.

### From

```
userCHR += str(user[i])
```

### To

```
userCHR += i
```

### New Code

```
user = input("Please enter a string: ")
user = user.upper()

userCHR = ""

for i in user:
    userCHR += i

print(userCHR)
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not wrong, the i is already a string. 
Maybe you can try:

```
for i in user:
  userCHR += i
```